# firebase scheduled notifications

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

For my app, I want users to schedule the time which they receive a specific notification. I was looking over the Firebase docs and could not find a method that would allow me to do this. Is there a way to allow users to schedule notifications with Firebase? My app is still using parse api but as of now parse notifications do not support scheduled pushes.

Comment: Hey! I am facing same problem, Have you figured out the method?

Answer (score 3):

**If plan to use the Firebase console** to send messages, there's a simple option to define a time in which you you want the message to go out.

**If you plan to send messages via SDK**. at this time there is no setting to handle scheduling, you'll have to handle it on your server.